# Not allowed to load local resource in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

In my `spring mvc` project i m having a issue about loading image to `client side`.
the `console` showing **Not allowed to load local resource**
I have figured out, that i need to create image `servlet` for viewing image.
but when i running the application no image showing..how can i solve this problems...

**`servlet` configuration in web.xml**

```
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>studentServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.bbs.response.web.controller.utils.StudentImageServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>   
      <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>studentServlet</servlet-name> 
       <url-pattern>/students/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

**image view servlet**

```
public class StudentImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String urlImage = request.getParameter("student"); 
    System.out.println("urlImage---"+urlImage);
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        ServletOutputStream out;
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:/jboss/welcome-content/students/"+urlImage);

        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        int ch = 0;
        while ((ch = bin.read()) != -1) {
            bout.write(ch);
        }

        bin.close();
        fin.close();
        bout.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

**my jquery script for viewing image**

```
<img style="height:50px; width:50px" name="student" src="C:/jboss/welcome-content/students/'+ studentBasic.photo+ '" />
```

Comment: Move the image under your application classpath resources.

Comment: when i moved the image to app path. i cannot upload image..im using jboss 7 as server.it will goes to jboss tmp folder.

Comment: Can you show how do you upload your images? Instead of servlet I would rather make another request mapping for retrieving the images based request.

Comment: i made another question check it out.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579373/image-uploading-using-spring-mvc-to-jboss-server-deployment-tmp-folder

Comment: if you want to display the image via servlet why are you having local file in img tag. Shouldn't you point to your servlet `<img style="height:50px; width:50px" name="student" src="/students/"+studentBasic.photo+"`